# Android user Info without google plus integration

Tags: android, userinfo

Is it possible to get user profile info like Name, profile pic, age,  birth date without google plus authentication/integration in android app?

Comment: from where do you want to get the information?

Comment: @PatriX1996 I want this information in android app so that I can sent it to server( obviously with user consent).

Comment: why not making a simple registration activity with all the fields you have mentioned above?

Comment: My app doesn't have any registration. I just want to use the users google profile.

Comment: take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people

Comment: @PatriX1996 this requires google+ authentication. anyway thanks!

Comment: i am pretty sure you cannot access other profiles without having google+ authentication, but if you have found a solution please share it with us ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85185/discussion-between-neo-and-patrix1996).